# Display same default camera application using UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ipad

How can we display the UiImagepicker controller interface with both camera and video mode and also with Photo Library icon button,same as default camera App for iPhone.

or How to remove cancel Button (shown in Camera view) and replace with different button. Is it possible and if will apple approve this approach.

Please help me out ??

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way.

```
BOOL hasCamera = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];


    if(hasCamera){

        UIActionSheet *actionSheet; 

        actionSheet = [[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Photo" 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Select from Library", @"Take a New Photo", nil] autorelease];

        actionSheet.actionSheetStyle  = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

        [actionSheet showInView:[self view]];
    }

    else {

        UIImagePickerController* imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing    = YES;   
        imagePickerController.delegate          = self;

        imagePickerController.sourceType  = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;  

        [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];

        [imagePickerController release];

    }
```

Actionsheet delegate method

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    //BOOL                               hasCamera = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    UIImagePickerController* imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing    = YES;   
    imagePickerController.delegate          = self;

    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        imagePickerController.sourceType  = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;  

    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    }
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];

    [imagePickerController release];
}
```

Image picker delegate

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    if(image)
    {
        [self.addPhotoButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: - I want to show photo library option to user in Camera Screen Only. Same as default iPhone Camera App. One and last option for me  is to customize every thing using overlay property.It would be better if I can achieve this functionality without customizing.